# Display $ in gridview Price Column

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ProductPrice" HeaderText="Price" />
```

How can I display a dollor sign before each record in the above column for every row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can format your data value as Currency by using `DataFormatString`

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ProductPrice" HeaderText="Price" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
```

if the culture is setted to a country who has a dollar currency, it will work fine.

Comment: It works, thanks I also found how to change it to other currencies:

USD: "{0:C}"

Euro: "&#8364; {0:N}" 

Japanese Yen: "¥#,##0.00;(¥#,##0.00);Zero"

GBP: "£#,##0.00;(£#,##0.00);Zero"

Comment: Remember that culture handling for an entire application may be convenient. You can check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use TemplateField instead of BoundField, you can format it like anything you want

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
       <ItemTemplate>
             $<%# Eval("ProductPrice")%>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```